# Laravel PHP 7.3 pdo_mysql reports missing driver, possible due to undefined symbol on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I'm trying to run Laravel php on a ubuntu 18.04 server. Unfortunately the following error occurs and prohibits me from accessing my database. I'm using the same configuration in Windows locally and that works.

I have the required packages installed such as the php7.3 and php7.3-mysql.

I also tried to reinstall the packages.

Does anyone know where to go from here?

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql'
>   (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql
>   (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol:
>   mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: create and info.php <?php  phpinfo(); ?> and check first there php version and pdo if showing there i think you have problem in you configuration because .so is use in windows instead of linux

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaYounas `.so` file extensions are standard unix/linux extensions and the OP is using Ubuntu. So I dont understand your comment

Comment: Have you tried removing the semicolon from the `` `pdo_mysql``` line in your php.ini file?

Comment: Yes i have, both in the fpm as in the cli folders in `/etc/php/7.3/`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on debian buster.
Problem was that `pdo_mysql.so` was loaded before `mysqlnd.so` and `pdo.so`.

I tried to put `extension=pdo` and `extension=mysqlnd` before `extension=pdo_mysql` in php.ini, which made it work, but threw an error about the three of them being loaded twice.
So I removed all 3 extension=... in php.ini, which did still work.

Seems like they are already loaded somewhere else (in /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/ I think), and enabling them in php.ini makes them just load twice, with the ones being enabled in php.ini having the highest priority.